# Are the extremas of $h(x)$ global?

Tags: calculus, number-theory, prime-numbers

It is well known that $li(x)$, the integral logarithm is a very good approximation of $\pi(x)$, the nunmber of primes not exceeding $x$.

So, a very good approximation for the probability, that a random number with $x$ digits is prime, is given by

$$f(x)=\frac{li(10^x)-li(10^{x-1})}{10^x-10^{x-1}}$$

I figured out that the function

$$g(x)=\frac{2000x}{(2000x^2-646x-141)\ln(10)}$$

is a superb approximation to $f(x)$ , using an interpolating tool at a very nice math-site from Arndt Brünner.

Let us define $h(x):=f(x)-g(x)$

It seems that for $x\ge 11$, the function $h(x)$ has minimum about $-4.334\cdot 10^{-8}\ $ and maximum about $2.1749\cdot 10^{-8}\ $.

> Are these extremas global extremas ? Can we rigorously prove that $|h(x)|<4.335\cdot 10^{-8}\ $ for all $x\ge 11$ ?

I tried to verify this with Wolfram Alpha, but the function seems to be too complicated. Any ideas ? The limit of $h(x)$, $x$ tending to $\infty$, should be $0$.

Comment: http://www.arndt-bruenner.de/mathe/scripts/regrnl.htm

Comment: Comment aside: *extrema* is already a plural in Latin.

Answer (score 1):

Both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ go to $0$ as $x \to \infty$, so $h(x)$ certainly has a global max and min somewhere on $[11,\infty)$.  All you need to do is find $N$ such that, say, $|f(x)| < 10^{-8}$ and $|g(x)| < \cdot 10^{-8}$ for $x \ge N$, and then show that your maximum and minimum are the maximum and minimum on $[11, N]$.  This is in principle a finite computation (although perhaps tedious): a finite number of sufficiently accurate approximations of $h$ at some points and bounds on $h'$ on some intervals (perhaps using interval arithmetic) will be sufficient.

Preliminary computations indicate that $N \approx 4.34 \cdot 10^7$.